# Нужно заменить регистр буквы в javascript

Tags: javascript, строки, replace

Не работает смена регистра при вводе.В чем может быть ошибка?

```js
function my_keypress2($event) {
  document.getElementById('div3').innerHTML = document.getElementById('text2').value;
  var x = ($event.keyCode || $event.which);
  var x_char2 = String.fromCharCode(x);

  if (
    (x_char2 == 'a')
  ) {
    x_char2 = x_char2.replace('a', 'A');
  }

}
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_touppercase.asp

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что не работает?

Comment: @Grundy потому что не работает)) Замена символа не происходит..

Comment: это ты как проверяла?

Comment: @Grundy в коде прописала:

<input type=text id="text2"
onKeyPress=my_keypress2(event);>
<div id="div3"></div>
</input> 

затем прописала что выше.
После мне нужно ввести символ 'a' в поле ввода и он должен перемениться и вывестись как 'А' в див

но у меня не работает

Comment: эм, а ты же знаешь, что в  input нельзя вкладывать элементы?

Comment: Ну и самое главное - где проверка того, что replace не работает? ты же в див выводишь значение инпута **до** того, как даже вызовешь `replace`, не говоря уже о том, что в данный момент ты нигде не используешь результат выполнения этой функции

Comment: @Grundy буду разбираться,спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Зачем что-то проверять, что-то переписывать, если можно сразу можно получить что надо?

```js
function my_keypress2($event) {
  document.getElementById('div3').innerHTML = document.getElementById('text2').value.toUpperCase();
}
```

```html
<input type=text id="text2" onKeyup="my_keypress2(event);"/>
<div id="div3"></div>
```

Comment: например затем, чтобы в другой регистр приводить не все символы, а только выборочные.